# Pointer Increment and Decrement(*--*++p) in c

Tags: c, increment, decrement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
 
    static char*s[]  = {"6642321","93456","134098","55513"};
    char ** str[] = {s+3,s+2,s+1,s};
    char ***p = str;
    **++p;
    printf("%s\n",*--*++p+2);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code on the printf statement `*++p` gives one address(s+1). In my understanding `--(s+1)` gives compilation error.  But this code gives output as `42321`. Why I am getting this answer.  Please could anyone explain this code ?

Comment: The two `*` dereference operators in `**++p;` do nothing useful — the result is ignored.  The compiler probably warns you about 'expression result unused' or something similar.  If it doesn't warn you about that, you aren't using enough compiler warnings.

Comment: It's probably best if you _don't_ write your code like that.  Future maintainers will thank you if you introduce local variables to make it more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `**++p;`:

- `++p` increments `p` so it points to `str+1` instead of its initial value, `str`.
- The second `*` produces the element `p` points to (after the increment), and that is `str[1]`.
- The first `*` produces the element that `str[1]` points to, and that is `*(s+2)` or, equivalently, `s[2]`.
- Then this value is discarded, as the expression does nothing with it.

In the `*--*++p+2` in the `printf`:

- `++p` increments `p` so it points to `str+2`.
- The second `*` produces the element `p` points to, and that is `str[2]`.
- The `--` decrements `str[2]`, so it changes from `s+1` to `s+0`, or just `s`.
- The first `*` produces the element `str[2]` points to (after the decrement), so it produces `*s` or, equivalently, `s[0]`. `s[0]` is a pointer to the first character of `"6642321"`.
- The `+2` produces a pointer to two characters beyond this, so it points to the `4` character.

Then this pointer to the `4` character is passed to `printf`. The characters starting at that point are `4`, `2`, `3`, `2`, `1`, and a null character, so printf prints `42321`.

Answer (score 4):

The result of the unary indirection operator `*` is always an **lvalue**.  This means it refers to a object that can be assigned to.

In this case subexpression `++p` in the `printf` is a pointer pointing to `str[2]`.  So `*++p` gives you the *object* `str[2]` which has the *value* `s+1`.

This means that `--*++p` is equivalent to `--str[2]`, which in turn sets its value to `s+0` (i.e. `s` after pointer decay).  Dereferencing that as `*--*++p+2` gives you the object `s[0]`.  Then 2 is added to the value stored there i.e. a pointer to the start of the string `"6642321"`, resulting in a pointer to the third character of that string.  That pointer is passed to `printf` which in turn prints `42321`.